# How can I warp and center multiple divs using Angular flex layout in a responsive way

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

How can I create an effect in the picture using [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview). I've been experimenting with `fxLayoutWrap` but it doesn't produce the below layout 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version for **Angular 6** and **flex-layout 6.0.0-beta.16**, since **fxLayoutWrap** has been deprecated in this version

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign=" none">
  <div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items | async" fxFlex.xs="100" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.md="33" fxFlex.lg="33" fxFlex.xl="33">
     {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to combine fxLayoutWrap with responsive fxFlex sizes for the elements. Setting fxLayoutGap="#" will also make sure there's a gap between row items. Setting a margin for the inner div's top/bottom can also handle the gap between rows (lots of times needed for Angular - Material items)

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch">
  <div fxFlex.lt-md="30" fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex.lt-md="30" fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

And if you haven't seen [this live demo](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) I'd highly recommend checking it out it's an amazingly great way to get a better understanding of how flex-layout works by watching the changes happen in real time.